# Why is the closeness centrality value higher for less connected nodes?

Tags: r, graph-theory, social-network, igraph

I built an igraph graph from a data frame containing the (symbolic) edge list and weight. This is the data frame:

```
>dput(y)
structure(list(from = c("Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", "Japan", "China", 
"Hong Kong", "Canada", "Hong Kong", "Canada", "China", "Canada", 
"China", "Japan", "Canada", "Canada", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", 
"Japan", "Canada", "Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", 
"China", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Canada", "Canada", "Hong Kong", 
"China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Kazakhstan", "Western Somoa", 
"Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", "Japan", "Canada", 
"Hong Kong", "Japan", "Western Somoa", "Canada", "China", "Canada", 
"Hong Kong", "Japan", "Hong Kong", "Canada", "Japan", "Canada", 
"Japan", "Canada", "Canada", "China", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Hong Kong", "Canada", "Japan", "Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", 
"Japan", "Kazakhstan", "Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", 
"Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Japan", "Canada", "Japan", 
"Canada", "China", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"China", "Japan", "Nauru", "Western Somoa", "Canada", "Japan", 
"Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Kazakhstan", "Canada", 
"China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", "Hong Kong", "Canada", 
"Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", 
"Canada", "Japan", "Anguilla", "Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "China", "Hong Kong", "Anguilla", "Canada", "China", 
"Japan", "Canada", "Hong Kong", "Canada", "Canada", "Kazakhstan", 
"Hong Kong", "China", "Hong Kong", "Canada", "Canada", "China", 
"Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Canada", "Canada", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Japan", "Canada", 
"China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", "Hong Kong", "Japan", 
"Canada", "Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Kazakhstan", 
"Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", "Hong Kong", 
"Canada", "China", "Japan", "China", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", "Canada", "Hong Kong", "Japan", 
"Canada", "Japan", "Canada", "Japan", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", 
"China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Kazakhstan", "Hong Kong", "Canada", 
"China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", "Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", 
"Japan", "Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", "China", 
"Japan", "China", "Hong Kong", "Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", 
"Japan", "Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", "China", 
"Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", "Hong Kong", "Canada", "China", 
"Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Japan", 
"Kazakhstan", "Canada", "Canada", "Hong Kong", "Canada", "Kazakhstan", 
"Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", "China", "Hong Kong", 
"Japan", "Canada", "Canada", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Canada", 
"Canada", "China", "Canada", "Hong Kong", "Japan", "Canada", 
"Canada"), to = c("Antigua", "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", 
"Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Australia", "Austria", 
"Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahamas", 
"Barbados", "Barbados", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belgium", "Belize", 
"Bermuda", "Bermuda", "Bermuda", "Bolivia", "Bolivia", "Botswana", 
"Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil", "British Virgin", "British Virgin", 
"British Virgin", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Cambodia", "Cambodia", 
"Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Canada", "Cayman Islands", 
"Cayman Islands", "Cayman Islands", "Cayman Islands", "Chile", 
"Chile", "China", "China", "China", "China", "Colombia", "Colombia", 
"Costa Rica", "Costa Rica", "Costa Rica", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", 
"Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Denmark", "Dominican Rep", "Ecuador", 
"Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Estonia", "Estonia", "Finland", 
"Finland", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Georgia", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Ghana", "Gibraltar", 
"Greece", "Grenada", "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guatemala", "Guernsey", 
"Guernsey", "Guinea", "Guyana", "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", 
"Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", 
"Hungary", "India", "India", "India", "India", "India", "Indonesia", 
"Indonesia", "Indonesia", "Indonesia", "Ireland-Rep", "Isle of Man", 
"Israel", "Israel", "Israel", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", "Italy", 
"Jamaica", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan", "Japan", "Jersey", 
"Jordan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kazakhstan", "Kazakhstan", 
"Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kenya", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Kyrgyzstan", 
"Luxembourg", "Macau", "Macau", "Madagascar", "Malaysia", "Malaysia", 
"Malaysia", "Malaysia", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Is", "Mauritania", 
"Mauritius", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Monaco", "Mongolia", 
"Mongolia", "Mongolia", "Mongolia", "Mozambique", "N. Mariana", 
"N. Mariana", "Namibia", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", 
"Netherlands", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", "New Zealand", 
"New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "North Korea", "Norway", "Norway", 
"Norway", "Pakistan", "Panama", "Papua N Guinea", "Paraguay", 
"Peru", "Peru", "Peru", "Philippines", "Philippines", "Philippines", 
"Poland", "Poland", "Portugal", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Romania", 
"Russian Fed", "Russian Fed", "Russian Fed", "Russian Fed", "Russian Fed", 
"Seychelles", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", "Singapore", 
"Slovak Rep", "South Africa", "South Africa", "South Africa", 
"South Africa", "South Korea", "South Korea", "South Korea", 
"South Korea", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sri Lanka", 
"Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Switzerland", 
"Switzerland", "Switzerland", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", 
"Tanzania", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Thailand", "Thailand", "Thailand", 
"Trinidad&Tob", "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turkey", "Turks/Caicos", 
"Uganda", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "Ukraine", "United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", 
"United Kingdom", "United Kingdom", "United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "Unknown", "Uruguay", "Uruguay", 
"Utd Arab Em", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", 
"Vietnam", "Vietnam", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), weight = c(0.181818181818182, 
0.00206462695287902, 0.307692307692308, 1.13507377979569, 0.0000658877157361476, 
0.000128992012556598, 0.0000833442375377445, 0.000124393550343687, 
0.00214332408131772, 0.00237330694216014, 0.0227272727272727, 
0.0952380952380952, 0.00305324865657059, 0.0285714285714286, 
0.000933166607566115, 10, 0.00353862050418265, 0.00207934791649339, 
0.00322232426249053, 0.0152225537356147, 0.00058555620226985, 
0.00114942528735632, 0.00539936395492611, 0.00948118932038835, 
0.0192104504850639, 0.00789016884961338, 0.00033894835172806, 
0.0549450549450549, 0.000925881346453689, 0.000575875979349087, 
0.00290874397526404, 0.00430639111505385, 0.000955749742664382, 
0.0454235748353395, 0.00476083924074136, 0.033003300330033, 4.54545454545455, 
0.000121466862989508, 0.00101148030142113, 0.00120044992863325, 
0.0010694054854085, 1.81818181818182, 0.0703828828828829, 0.0385163501906559, 
0.0571428571428571, 0.00455956848243882, 0.000165705327210853, 
0.0263157894736842, 0.00151259614439243, 0.0000128692526400307, 
0.000460301736994635, 0.0156683327327139, 0.000814186383546921, 
0.00117647058823529, 0.0032802479867478, 0.153846153846154, 0.714285714285714, 
0.00395255354721918, 0.00195960470853819, 0.0384452731536658, 
0.00638044012275967, 0.00817313979338303, 2.8169014084507, 0.00547849144259637, 
0.000704225352112676, 0.013219819152874, 0.014553922282055, 0.00373452041288858, 
0.443458980044346, 0.00739131077505285, 0.00353104850954442, 
0.000131876711100327, 0.0281159501785363, 0.00131941090941716, 
0.00145577359809003, 0.00975609756097561, 0.000316217732352046, 
0.0241295273025601, 0.00360200703832175, 0.00197323503991854, 
0.15852885225111, 0.250062515628907, 0.00480600558457849, 0.2, 
0.0103305785123967, 0.355366027007818, 0.0961815908435125, 0.293944738389183, 
0.0435824798431031, 2.60416666666667, 0.138236107271219, 1, 0.778210116731518, 
0.00138637416020385, 0.0000939575522328824, 0.000410069838994279, 
0.00581010260641203, 1.59235668789809, 0.16, 0.0485885039599631, 
0.00703774341795047, 3.86100386100386, 0.00119843292910191, 0.000466218071638136, 
0.0318197728068222, 0.00238505808808974, 0.000981843745458973, 
0.00272089593661401, 0.000585426623797826, 0.00243684905669573, 
0.181851245681033, 0.00137057834294337, 2.22222222222222, 0.4, 
0.00147312721337364, 0.000647577380640156, 0.00341300422871224, 
0.00133147814045763, 0.00326616999108336, 0.000924214417744917, 
0.110791048083315, 0.00139081478102317, 0.00141370530747384, 
0.000845480063580101, 0.00311571128572942, 47.6190476190476, 
0.25, 0.0141719339021003, 0.00174668827902297, 0.000319601444215006, 
0.00716845878136201, 0.0310269934843314, 0.0448671931083991, 
0.00315953769644426, 0.00619859044053382, 0.0478354460655346, 
0.0322102686336404, 0.00134714788585347, 0.000730767656808124, 
0.062802235759593, 0.23121387283237, 0.0835421888053467, 0.000920126572611328, 
0.000781907902195832, 0.0392927308447937, 0.0858811405015459, 
0.0224628240262366, 0.0036036036036036, 3.55871886120996, 0.000926080272638032, 
0.047614512903533, 0.00412002455534635, 0.0500125031257814, 0.00630548829701372, 
0.00928720687253309, 0.00421730952521529, 0.145985401459854, 
0.209643605870021, 4.76190476190476, 0.0305352835201075, 0.27708506511499, 
0.000558663587312973, 0.00380255607819576, 0.000586250663196063, 
0.0000968310677445643, 0.000833333333333333, 0.000593363349607312, 
0.0451773209848656, 0.000422893419862966, 0.00116533410711518, 
0.0166251039068994, 0.333889816360601, 0.0048700191878756, 0.00961482991365883, 
2.21238938053097, 0.00187265917602996, 0.0284762365805735, 0.00187379608601474, 
0.0983864620228257, 0.000866097813622679, 0.00999050901643439, 
0.00965437343116432, 0.0868734254191643, 0.000549096352133294, 
0.000266489291394315, 0.0101821588213133, 0.0214864313186223, 
0.00129959582569821, 0.138255219134522, 0.0022629912671167, 0.0670061645671402, 
0.00448448592095645, 0.000285714285714286, 2.25225225225225, 
0.0291247997670016, 0.0235982631678308, 0.0205680906641436, 0.000745643762727207, 
0.000632570284884354, 0.000228682659817164, 0.000642573997215084, 
0.209819555182543, 0.000627575412599455, 0.00480632897399295, 
0.0087861109158642, 0.00320414231518507, 0.00209362699941378, 
0.00109572830320994, 0.000366587190563752, 0.00046947320880713, 
0.00183926650051959, 0.200120072043226, 0.00783570102099184, 
0.0120481927710843, 0.0218145328417792, 0.000933973665678523, 
0.00507735348027194, 0.00151236052255081, 0.000885327903322193, 
0.0000662420858096005, 0.00347651958671135, 0.00174158682942376, 
0.0015021736452647, 0.0683386865304449, 0.0108056708160443, 0.000505717899429904, 
0.00252027561734151, 0.0334985930590915, 8.54700854700855, 0.0219818869251737, 
0.000844268723980693, 0.00499158917224477, 0.00118176349839812, 
0.000439502676351548, 0.0316866820875186, 0.00430590899891922, 
0.0203256163743166, 0.00048780487804878, 0.0111111111111111, 
0.0204611953430319, 1.17647058823529, 0.0219058050383352, 0.15527950310559, 
0.0000634869643803212, 0.000232375103610249, 0.000540630840502549, 
0.000100590961841724, 0.00000358401578847838, 0.000669877164624323, 
0.000130258571079106, 0.0000202845599203872, 1.84162062615101, 
0.0344827586206897, 71.4285714285714, 0.0145674911866678, 0.363372093023256, 
0.0015525443096146, 0.00415454923140839, 0.210526315789474, 0.0691658597316365, 
0.0988044659618615, 0.019047619047619, 0.229252636405319)), row.names = c(19L, 
27L, 55L, 64L, 72L, 74L, 82L, 88L, 119L, 128L, 146L, 147L, 153L, 
156L, 178L, 179L, 192L, 193L, 205L, 220L, 225L, 228L, 231L, 243L, 
246L, 264L, 273L, 276L, 283L, 288L, 308L, 309L, 312L, 340L, 364L, 
368L, 369L, 392L, 404L, 410L, 411L, 441L, 444L, 445L, 447L, 449L, 
460L, 469L, 488L, 497L, 504L, 527L, 530L, 533L, 553L, 557L, 559L, 
589L, 602L, 613L, 636L, 649L, 665L, 672L, 674L, 686L, 708L, 725L, 
730L, 749L, 759L, 783L, 785L, 792L, 798L, 832L, 847L, 849L, 859L, 
866L, 892L, 903L, 909L, 930L, 931L, 935L, 939L, 943L, 945L, 951L, 
954L, 959L, 961L, 969L, 971L, 981L, 987L, 1006L, 1010L, 1020L, 
1045L, 1047L, 1052L, 1057L, 1059L, 1082L, 1084L, 1089L, 1091L, 
1117L, 1139L, 1148L, 1152L, 1156L, 1173L, 1175L, 1181L, 1185L, 
1214L, 1216L, 1223L, 1228L, 1230L, 1235L, 1257L, 1267L, 1268L, 
1276L, 1280L, 1281L, 1285L, 1298L, 1301L, 1305L, 1312L, 1314L, 
1371L, 1385L, 1386L, 1399L, 1409L, 1411L, 1417L, 1420L, 1440L, 
1443L, 1451L, 1454L, 1459L, 1474L, 1481L, 1485L, 1511L, 1519L, 
1520L, 1522L, 1523L, 1540L, 1553L, 1554L, 1557L, 1577L, 1579L, 
1587L, 1596L, 1598L, 1624L, 1625L, 1629L, 1631L, 1644L, 1658L, 
1667L, 1669L, 1683L, 1704L, 1719L, 1732L, 1739L, 1749L, 1751L, 
1754L, 1770L, 1773L, 1774L, 1789L, 1803L, 1823L, 1830L, 1841L, 
1866L, 1902L, 1903L, 1913L, 1919L, 1921L, 1982L, 1993L, 1995L, 
2000L, 2006L, 2030L, 2072L, 2074L, 2081L, 2086L, 2104L, 2105L, 
2109L, 2112L, 2135L, 2137L, 2151L, 2172L, 2173L, 2200L, 2201L, 
2210L, 2216L, 2239L, 2240L, 2246L, 2251L, 2275L, 2276L, 2280L, 
2282L, 2296L, 2297L, 2305L, 2306L, 2310L, 2312L, 2332L, 2336L, 
2349L, 2360L, 2362L, 2381L, 2383L, 2385L, 2394L, 2405L, 2429L, 
2431L, 2444L, 2453L, 2499L, 2502L, 2513L, 2523L, 2561L, 2566L, 
2570L, 2582L, 2608L, 2615L, 2617L, 2633L, 2637L, 2638L, 2670L, 
2680L), class = "data.frame")
```

The links represent exports and imports of goods, the weights are the reciprocal of the value of the traded good.

I used the following code

```
g <- graph_from_data_frame(y, directed=TRUE, vertices=unique(c(y$from,y$to)))

closeness_score=as.data.frame(closeness(g, mode="out"))
```

to calculate the closeness centrality of the resulting network (mode "out" measures paths from a vertex).

In the first three positions of the rank in `closeness_score` we find:

```
Nauru           0.00368870721
Anguilla        0.00367258982
Western Somoa   0.00367225767
```

But I cannot understand these results. In my network, Nauru, Anguilla, and Western Somoa are poorly connected to other countries. In particular, they are involved only in the following links:

```
from            to          weight
Western Somoa   Canada      1.818181818
Western Somoa   China       0.015668333
Nauru           Hong Kong   0.005810103
Western Somoa   Hong Kong   1.592356688
Anguilla        Japan       0.110791048
Anguilla        Kazakhstan  0.014171934
```

Why do they have the highest closeness value instead?

Comment: When I use your data and your code, I get an entirely different result. I get different numbers for the closeness values and the three countries that you mention have the _least_ closeness, not the most. What happens for you if you start a new R session and run your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your network is not connected. To be specific, it is not strongly connected as a directed graph. The concept of closeness makes little sense for disconnected networks. This is pointed out in the igraph documentation.

A short explanation:

The closeness of a vertex is defined as the inverse of the mean distance to all other vertices. What if not all other vertices are reachable? R/igraph 1.3 will only consider reachable one when computing distances and doing the averaging. However, this means that the closeness values of vertices from which a different set of other vertices are reachable will not be comparable.

Consider alternative centrality measures. Harmonic centrality is often used as an alternative to closeness in disconnected networks.